# make navbar smaller on ipad

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I do not know how I can make my navbar smaller on **Ipad**. As it is now, the navbar is hanging under my logo, and they should be on a row instead. I tried to set col-sm-12 because I thought everything in the div would take 12 col, but that does not work.

[My website](https://vouzalis.com/index.php)

Does anyone have an idea how I can do that?

**HTML**

```
<!-- begin nav -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">

                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>

                            <i class="fa fa-reorder"  style="padding-left: 4px; color: red;"></i>

                    </button>
                    <!-- begin logo in navigation -->
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>/index.php">
                        <img src="https://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>/images/graphic/vouzalis-webdesign.png">
                    </a>
                    <!-- end logo in navigation -->
                </div>

                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-main pull-right">

                        <!-- begin navigation items -->
                        <li>
                            <a href="https://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>/index.php">Hjem</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="https://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']  ?>/kompetencer.php">Kompetencer</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="https://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']  ?>/portfolio.php">Portfolio</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="https://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']  ?>/om-mig.php">Om Mig</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="https://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']  ?>/artikler/index-artikler.php">Artikler</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="https://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']  ?>/kontakt.php">Kontakt</a>
                        </li>
                        <!-- end navigation items -->
                    </ul>   
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<!-- end nav -->
```

**CSS**

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {

/* Navigation */
.nav-main {
    float: left!important;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse, 
.navbar-default .navbar-form {
    border: none;
}
.nav-main li:first-child {
    border-top: 1px dashed #444;
}

.navbar .dropdown-menu>li>a {
    padding: 15px 20px;
}

.nav-pills>li {
    float: none;
}
.nav-main {
    width: 100%;
}
.navbar-brand {
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 15px;
}
.fixednav .nav-main {
    background: #171717;
    margin-top: 14px;
}
.fixednav .nav-pills>li+li {
    margin-left: 0px;
}
.dropdown-menu {
    float: none;
    position: static;
}
```

Comment: If you're using bootstrap, you should add the bootstrap js component, so that your navbar collapses when you're in mobile devices. Check out the documentation on navs: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I have added the relevant CSS to my question. I would actually like that the navbar is not collapsing on Ipad, but first on mobile. That is working fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your tablet breakpoint in your css.

use another media query like `@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {}`

define the spacing and height that you want there and it will take affect.

**EDIT**

I see you have a breakpoint define for min-width: 769px and max-width 991px

You can keep that breakpoint if you wish but after looking at your site the real issue is that you have your wrapping **container class set to 750px** and margin 0 auto to center it.

**The reason your nav bar is nesting under your name element is because this container is not wide enough to display both of them inline.**

You can make the container larger say 100% width and adjust your margins or make your navigation buttons smaller.

or a combination of both.

Comment: I noticed you have defined up to 991px but the screen with of a standard I pad is 1024px make sure your media queries cover that

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So I have to do something like this? `.navbar {
 width: 100%;
}`

Comment: Also try defining the width of your .navbar-header class and setting display to inline-block also try the same with your navbar-collapse class

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer again. I am not quite sure where you see the container class for 750px; ?

Comment: your wrapper <div class="container"> is being set to width: 750px by the bootstrap css (not you) you would have to define the container in your css file and override it

Comment: So I can override with: `.container {
    width: 100%;
}`?

Comment: yes and then adjust your other elements as necessary

Comment: Thank you a lot for the answer. I will accept it now. I actually came to another solution. I think the logo is to big on an ipad and mobiledevice, so I will try to find a way, so when you are on a mobiledevice, the logo will get a littler bit smaller, so there is also place for the navbar